# How do you start a section with 0.0?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How would I go about adding the "A short preface" section? 
I know `\section*{0.0 A Short Preface}` would probably be fine, but TeX is awesome and there has to be a better way.

This is sort of what I'm looking for (done in Google Docs):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `\setcounter{section}{-1}` will work for the section.

Comment: Do you really want to have this? `\setcounter{section}{-1}\setcounter{subsection}{-1}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At its simplest, setting the section counter to `-1` will cause the next section to be `0`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section{text}
\end{document}
```

To change the appearance of sectioning, for example to add the subsection number by default, one needs to redefine `\thesection`, as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section{A Short Preface}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. It comes out with just a 0 instead of a 0.0, do you think that's fine? For my own knowledge, is it possible to get a 0.0?

Comment: @GrantStenger Whether it is `0` or `0.0` depends on the class, and such.  You did not provide enough information on those issues to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Got it, what sort of information is needed? Thanks for your time, apologies if this is trivial. The document class is currently [11 pt, oneside]{article}.

Comment: @GrantStenger For article, the default is just in integer section number.  One has to be at the subsection level to get `x.x` format.  Unless you have packages loaded that changes the format of the sectioning.  So what packages you load is important to know.  This is why it is important, with your question, to post code that produces the image, and not just the image itself.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. I'm using geometry, amsmath, graphicx, amssymb, and chngcntr. I'm practicing LaTeX by formatting a paper for my brother and I wasn't sure if he wanted the context posted here so I just took a screenshot. Definitely good to note for the future though.

Comment: @GrantStenger for the `x.x` sectioning format, a different fix is applied... redefining `\thesection`.  See my edited answer.  There are of course other ways, and packages for such things (the `titlesec` package is a popular one).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Update with [xassoccnt v.0.8](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r9jf1b94kjnzxk/xassoccnt.0.8.tar.gz?dl=0) -- usage of cascaded suspension of counters, i.e. all counters in a counter reset list will be suspended:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\CascadeSuspendCounters{chapter}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\section{Foo}


\begin{figure}

\caption{A foo figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A foo table}
\end{table}



\subsection{My First subsection}
\blindtext
\section{Foobar}
\subsection{Foobar subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Foobar Again}
\blindtext


\ResumeAllSuspendedCounters

\chapter{Another chapter}


\begin{figure}
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}



\SuspendCounters{chapter,section}

\chapter{Yet another chapter}

\section{Foo section in yet another chapter}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Using `\SuspendCounters` from `xassoccnt` to hold counters fixed and resuming them later on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\SuspendCounters{section}
\SuspendCounters{subsection}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{My First subsection}
\blindtext
\ResumeSuspendedCounters{section}
\ResumeSuspendedCounters{subsection}
\section{Foobar}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]